# Qlikview summarize data previous year for selections in year or year and month

Tags: qlikview

I want to summarize figures for the previous year based on multiple possible  selections in Year, Month and Day to provide a previous year comparison on my dashboard: see screenshot.

I have found plenty of working examples for previous year summaries applied to a fixed dimension but none to assist with providing a summary for a range of possible selections.

I have tried numerous set analysis expressions so far, and  I have tried adding a variable which calculates 1 year prior and including it in expressions, but the difficulty has been where to include the '1' or select from all possible records in the expression.

Most recent attempt as below calculates but returns 0.

```
sum( {$<Discharge= {$(#vPrevYr)}>}daycase)
```

Can anyone assist?

[image]

Comment: (based on your screenshot) you have selected May/2017 and want to show numbers for May/2016?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: 
Changed the variable to 
vYearMinus1= Discharge_Year-1

Used in expression
sum({$}daycase)

All hunky dory, selections all (multiple or other) produce previous years figures: Yay!

Table from which figure will be extracted includes the year dimension: see attached screenshots [Table including dimensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1SA2.png) and finished result [Finished result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG7ua.png)

Comment: Not sure why expressions not posting properly in original posts: expression is      sum({$<Discharge_Year= {$(vYearMinus1)}>}daycase)